# How can i ensure that my app support minimum Google Play Services 4.1 version?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I need to get ConnectionResult.SUCCESS when I'm checking Google Play Services availability if installed Google Play Services version is 4.1+:

```
int code = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
```

Currently I'm geting code == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED,
when Google Play Services version is 5.0.84.

I know that all i need is to add some tag to manifest witch should include GooglePlayServices version code. But i do not know witch one and what version number belong to 4.1. 
Please advice.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28513337/950427

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what i found till now:

No need to do any changes on manifest file.

Version code for Google Play Services is 7 digits number and its complicated from same digits as version name.

For example:

version 4.1.00 has code 4100000
version 6.5.99 has code 6599000

So, when i need to check if installed GooglePlayServices is updated enough i do:

```
int code = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    ...
    if (code == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION_CODE >= 4100000)
            result = true;// Meets minimum version requirements
    }
```

Comment: How can u get the minimum version required for your app (in your case it's 4100000)?

Comment: When i check if google play services available at all and recive code ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED all i need to check if existing google play services is meet minimum expected version, so i check GooglePlayServicesUtil.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION_CODE value. When it is too old  I can show to user warring about it and restrict app usage until user gets last updated google play services version.

Comment: I meant how do you get the number 4100000? My app use many GPS features and I don't know what the minimum version required to run all of those features.

Comment: btw your code is wrong because GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION_CODE is version of your GPS library declare in your manifest, not on device.

Comment: Wayne: you right about GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION_CODE but it is not related to my project AndroidManifest, it is related to GPS library project itself witch include its own manifest file. 
About exact minimum version: In my project  I'm using Ads with DFP support, witch is available  starting from GPS version 4.1. Every future and info about minimum required version you can find here: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/gms-packages.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need to support GMS back to 4.1 you need to include the following dependency

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.32'
```

Alternatively extract `<android-sdk>\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services\4.1.32\play-services-4.1.32.aar` and import it as a library project if you're using Eclipse.

This will add the GMS interface library of version 4.1.32 to your project. This also means you have to use older APIs (before unified `GoogleApiClient`).